# Provide a file handle to a PHP function expecting a file path

Tags: php, php-stream-wrappers

Using [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel), I would like to read a file from the internet. The PHPExcel library seems suited to opening only local files, not URLs. Here's what I tried:

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$string = file_get_contents('http://opendatakit.org/wp-content/uploads/static/sample.xls');

$stream = fopen('php://memory','r+');
fwrite($stream, $string);
rewind($stream);

$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('php://memory');
```

This is the error I received:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Reader_Exception' with
>   message 'Could not open php://memory for reading! File does not
>   exist.'

I also tried passing the URL directly (`PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('http://opendatakit.org/wp-content/uploads/static/sample.xls')`). Similar error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Reader_Exception' with
>   message 'Could not open
>   http://opendatakit.org/wp-content/uploads/static/sample.xls for
>   reading! File does not exist.'

EDIT: Also tried a temporary file

```
$string = file_get_contents('http://opendatakit.org/wp-content/uploads/static/sample.xls');

$temp = tmpfile();
fwrite($temp, $string);
fseek($temp, 0);

$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($temp);
```

Different error this time:

> Warning: pathinfo() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given
>   in /project/vendor/phpoffice/phpexcel/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php
>   on line 224
>
> Warning: file_exists() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path,
>   resource given in
>   /project/vendor/phpoffice/phpexcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Reader/Excel2007.php
>   on line 81
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Reader_Exception' with
>   message 'Could not open Resource id #10 for reading! File does not
>   exist.'

Comment: Is your php.ini set to allow opening external URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your thinking is good. But PHPExcel needs a filepath to work correctly.
You can try with this sample :

```
$string = file_get_contents('http://opendatakit.org/wp-content/uploads/static/sample.xls');

$tmp = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), "FOO");
file_put_contents($tmp, $string);

$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($tmp);

//Perform all your operations
// ...

unlink($tmp);
```

See PHP Manual for [tempnam()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php)

Comment: Thanks! A real temporary file seems like the only solution. Could you explain more about `tempnam()`? It looked like a typo but I see it is a real PHP function!

Comment: tempnam() function just create a uniq file into the directory passed in the first argument. It also returns the filename including the path so you're ready to work with this !